# Computationally solve system of equations with singular matrix

Tags: python, r, wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra

I have this singular matrix (I'll call it A)

```
-3a          1         0    0
 3a    -2a - 1         2    0
 0      2a        -a-b-2    3
 0           0     a+b     -3
```

I'm trying to solve Ax = 0, such that the sum of the elements in x is 1.  I want to solve for x in terms of a and b.  I know how to do this by hand (use Gaussian elimination to write all components in terms of the fourth component, then set the fourth component so that the solution is normalized).  But is there any way to do this computationally?  I would be fine doing it in either Python, Mathematica, or R.  (Or MATLAB but I don't think there's a way to do it in MATLAB.)

The code I was copying did it by adding a fifth row to the matrix,

```
1    1    1    1
```

and then using QR decomposition to find a least-squares solution.  However, I don't think I can do this because I don't have values for a and b, and I want to solve for the solution in terms of a and b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In[1]:= A = {{-3a,1,0,0}, {3a,-2a-1,2,0}, {0,2a,-a-b-2,3}, {0,0,a+b,-3}};
x = {p, q, r, s};
sol = Reduce[A.x==0 && p+q+r+s==1 && Det[A]==0, x, Backsubstitution->True]

Out[3]= (1+3*a+3*a^2+a^3+a^2*b) != 0 && 
p == 1/(1+3*a+3*a^2+a^3+a^2*b) && 
q == (3*a)/(1+3*a+3*a^2+a^3+a^2*b) && 
r == (3*a^2)/(1+3*a+3*a^2+a^3+a^2*b) && 
s == (a^3 + a^2*b)/(1+3*a+3*a^2+a^3+a^2*b)

In[4]:= x=x/.ToRules[sol (* Watch out for that denominator!!! *)];
Simplify[A.x]

Out[5]= {0, 0, 0, 0}

In[6]:= Simplify[Total[x]]

Out[6]= 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: Do you know how I could do this on a larger system, say 11x11?  It takes forever to run when I try it.

Comment: If you look at the size of the determinant of an 11x11 matrix made up of small integers and about the same percentage of expressions containing variables as in your 4x4 problem then I think you will get some idea of the size of problem you are asking it to solve. Or, short answer, no. But, some problems where you are really interested in what the answer will be may be worth waiting days or weeks. But it is annoying to not know if it is making progress or will ever give a useful answer if it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it in MATLAB but I couldn't progress further than this.

```
syms a b
A = [ -3*a,         1,           0,  0;
       3*a, - 2*a - 1,           2,  0;
         0,       2*a, - a - b - 2,  3;
         0,         0,       a + b, -3;
         1,         1,           1,  1];
x = solve(A,[0 0 0 0 1]')
```

I got the following warnings:

```
Warning: 20 equations in 2 variables. 
Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.
```